# argument of Node.js's call back function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

The code below is creating a GET route using node.js and mongoose. In the findById function we used a callback function which takes err and foundCampground. I interpret callback function as some sort of higher order function but how can you pass a function with its argument included? When findById is executed, what is the variable passed to the call back function? I am asking this because err, and foundCampground is not defined anywhere else, so I have no idea what is supposed to be passed to the call back function during execution.

```
app.get("/campgrounds/:id", function(req, res){
    Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundCampground){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        res.render("show", {campground: foundCampground});
    });
 });
```

Comment: `findById` _should_ call your callback with 1 or 2 arguments, and that's what `err` and `foundCampground` will be. How come you didn't have the same question about the callback to `app.get`?

Comment: why are you asking me `.findById`? when the `app.get` practically do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***parameter*** for the 2nd ***argument*** of Campground.findById, which is `err` and `foundCampground` are not defined anywhere, because it is... a ***parameter*** of a function-definition.

In case you're not familiar with the differences between *parameter* and *argument*.

*parameter* is variable in the declaration of function.
while *Arguments* is the actual value passed into a function for that parameter.

for example:

`req.headers.body` and `function (err, foundCampground){ ... }` is an *Argument*.

Meanwhile `err` and `foundCampground` is a parameter.

As for, what `arguments` will be passed into `err` and `foundCampground`? That will be handled by the logic `Campground.findById`

here is an example of how, you write your own function that accept a callback

```js
const items = [{ id: 1, name: 'Adam' }, { id: 2, name: 'Ramadoka' }, ];
function findById(searchedId, callback){
  // the 2nd argument is a callback function, that we will call 
  // by passing error (if not found) as the first argument (or null otherwise)
  // and the item (if the item is found) as the 2nd argument (or null otherwise)
  for (const item of items) {
     if(item.id === searchedId) {
         return callback(null, item);
     }
  }
  return callback(new Error('not found'), null);
}


// and then you can call it with something like:
findById(2, function (error, item) {
   if (error) { console.error(error); }
   if (item) { console.log(item); }
});
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It might be better to put items inside of the function definition?

Comment: it could be defined either way, haha, just that if I define the items inside the body of findById, it'll be re-initialized everytime it is called.

since it is static anyway, it just feels natural to initialize it once.